What does this author mean by a simple compactness argument?
In the book "Ten Lectures on the Interface between Analytic Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis", in the first chapter they say that a sequence of points {$u_n$} is uniformly distributed if:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\alpha)=\alpha\quad(1)$$
for all $0\leq\alpha\leq1.$ Where $Z(N;\alpha)=$card{$n\in\mathbb{Z}:1\leq n\leq N,0\leq u_n\leq \alpha\pmod{1}$}. Basically $Z(N;\alpha)$ counts how many points of a sequence mod 1 are in the interval $[0,\alpha]$ up to a specific $N$.
Now later it's stated that "By a simple compactness argument it may be seen that if {$u_n$} is uniformly distributed then the limit $(1)$ is attained uniformly in $\alpha$"
So my main question is, what does the author mean here by simple compactness argument? With one of my professors we came up with a proof but it wasn't a a simple compactness argument at all. Also any ideas about how to prove that would be very helpful.

as I stated in the post, with one professor of my college we came up with a solution. In hopes that this is useful for someone else I'll give here the thought process alongside the idea of the proof.
Step 1: How to use compactness?
We started by searching some way to use a compactness in our argument. The first and the only thing that crossed our mind was to use the classic definition of compactness. Note that:
$$[0,1]\subseteq\bigcup_{\beta\in[0,1]}B_\delta(\beta)$$
For some fixed and small $\delta$. Therefore by compactness of $[0,1]$
$$[0,1]\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^mB_\delta(\beta_i)$$
So if we let $\alpha\in[0,1],$ then there is some index $j$ such that $\alpha\in B_\delta(\beta_j)$ so if we can prove that the limit is uniform in $B_\delta(\beta)$ then we are set.
Step 2: Prove the limit is uniform.
Given the fact that $\{u_n\}$ is uniformly distribuited we can use the definition and the Riemann integral criterion listed here. Given $\varepsilon>0$ for some $N_1(\beta),$ a positive integer, if $N\geq N_1$ then:
$$\left|\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\beta)-\beta\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$
Also notice that for the fixed $\delta$ such that $B_\delta(\beta)\subseteq [0,1],$ we have that there exists some $N_2(\beta,\delta)$ positive integer, such that:
$$\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_{B_\delta(\beta)}(u_n)-\int_0^1\chi_{B_\delta(\beta)}(y)\,dy\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$
if $N\geq N_2,$ also note that $\int_0^1\chi_{B_\delta(\beta)}(y)\,dy=2\delta.$  Now take $\alpha\in B_\delta(\beta)$ and $M=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, if $N\geq M$, by doing some work using the triangle inequality we get:
$$\left|\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\alpha)-\alpha\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\alpha)-\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\beta)-2\delta\right|+\left|\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\beta)-\beta\right|+|\beta-\alpha|+2\delta$$
And by the fact that:
$$\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\alpha)-\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\beta)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_{[\beta,\alpha]}(u_n)\leq\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_{B_\delta(\beta)}(u_n)$$
for some $\delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{9}$ we have:
$$\left|\frac{1}{N}Z(N;\alpha)-\alpha\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{9}+2\frac{\varepsilon}{9}=\varepsilon$$
Step 3: Use Steps 1 and 2
In step 2 we proved that the limit is uniform in $B_\delta(\beta)$ so by step 1 we can see that if we pick $M^\prime=\max_{i}\{N_i\},$ where each $N_i$ is the positive integer such that the limit is uniform in $B_\delta(\beta_i),$ we take away the dependence on the $\alpha$ that we choosed, therefore we conclude that the limit is attained uniformly in $\alpha.$
Some remarks
I know that I could have presented this in a more rigourous way, but I think this is a great way to encourage someone else to try to understand for themselves while also filling the gaps, like in step 2 we asumed that $\beta<\alpha$ or what happens in the border of the interval. But regarding all of that I encourage to anyone who reads this to give any kind of suggestions or corrections, I'd love to read all of those :3.

Yes, this is exactly the argument that Montgomery had in mind. I would definitely call this a simple compactness argument. Here "simple" means that I could give this to an advanced undergraduate student as a homework problem and expect them to solve it - after all, Montgomery's lectures are aimed at graduate students and above.

@PeterHumphries Thank you for the feedback, now it makes a lot of sense the "simple" part, but to be honest I would have prefered that Montgomery used a different word there, because that made me overthink the argument a lot lol, but thanks again.
